# ASCII communication using Pyserial

Tags: serial-port, ascii, pyserial, uart, serial-communication

I’m trying to send ASCII characters from an NVIDIA Jetson nano to a Roboteq motor controller. (MAX3232 to convert the logic level)

Using Pyserial for serial comm.
Sending 3 variable values for motor control, eg: ‘!VAR 1 250’ (‘!’ Is the start of the command)
Following is a snippet of the code,

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(

port = '/dev/ttyTHS1',
baudrate = 115200,
parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
timeout = 1
)

command = ‘!VAR 1 250’ + ’ \r’
ser.write(command.encode())
data =
ser.readline().decode().strip()

print(data)
```

Coming to the issue,
‘!VAR 1 250’ does not pass the same value when sent every time.

Data string gets corrupted.
Is this because I am sending the ASCII command the wrong way? Is it being transferred in bytes?

I feel I am missing something here. How do we send an ASCII string via pyserial?

Comment: *"MAX3232 to convert the logic level"* -- How did you verify that your circuit is fully functional in both directions?  *"... does not pass the same value ... Data string gets corrupted."* -- What symptoms did you observe to reach these conclusions?

Comment: @sawdust, I sent a string to activate emergency stop and release on the drive controller. 
Also, retrieved the motor amps from the drive controller. 2 way communication works. 
But for powering motor sometimes, data gets corrupted. 

Is this how we send an ascii string?

Comment: *"data gets corrupted"* -- One more time: What symptoms did you observe?  At best, you would have to observe & verify that `x` was sent, and `y` was received to claim that  *"data gets corrupted"* .  But if you send `x`, and no response occurs, then claiming that *"data gets corrupted"* is a faulty conclusion.  There are other possible reasons for no response.

Comment: Symptoms observed- x is sent, x is observed. 
Then, again when x is sent for the second time, x is not observed rather no character goes through. 

- communication is inconsistent. I am baffled with this. 

- Is it because there’s no checksum or any other reason?

Comment: Why not try something similar with PuTTY instead of PySerial? If that works, why not try to find out the difference between them? If that doesn't work, it may be due to the hardware or device driver, not the application program. Or is it a specification that always returns the same value for the same command in the first place? Isn't it a value that constantly fluctuates due to factors such as temperature and current?

Comment: You probably cannot rule out either HW or SW (or both) as the cause of your poorly-defined problem.  SOP is to remove untested components, and instead test with just one component at a time.  Start first with your HW circuit, and use a proven terminal emulator (e.g. minicom or Putty) instead of your code.  Hand type each message for transmit, or use the plain file transmit capability in minicom.  *" Is it because there’s no checksum or any other reason?"* -- How are we supposed to know what your mystery device is and what it expects?

Comment: @kunif thank you for your suggestion. Will check if its a software or hardware fault